# How to prevent converting a null pointer into a reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, singleton

In my application, I have a Singleton that represents *"the system"*. This object is created first and destroyed last and all other objects are supposed to be managed by it, which means, each object will be created directly or indirectly by this *system* object (in its `run` method) and all objects will (hopefully) be removed before the *system* gets unavailable.

The problem is that an optional access to the *system* object (via pointer) introduces lots of not-null checking code. I know that dereferencing a null pointer results in undefined behaviour. Is using the good old C-`assert` the best I can do?

```
// this is mostly pseudo-code, but should compile if 
// there is an appropriate MySys header
#include "MySys.h"

class MySysImplementation: public MySys 
{
public:
    MySysImplementation();
    void run();
    // ...
};

/// pointing to system object during runtime
namespace {
MySys* g_sys = NULL;
}

MySys& MySys::Instance()
{
    assert(g_sys);
    return *g_sys;
}

int main()
{
    {
        MySysImplementation sys;
        g_sys = &sys;
        sys.run();
    } // <---------- HERE all application-specific objects should be gone
    g_sys = NULL; // in real code this RAII-ensured
}
```

Comment: You can also throw an exception. An assert can be removed when in release mode. An exception will be thrown in release mode and you can catch it somewhere and deal with the issue if it makes sense. If not your program just terminates without running on invalid memory before and maybe format your PC

Comment: Have you considered keeping it as a static variable? It would move the cleanup out of `main`, but maybe you can live with that.

Comment: @Hayt good point, is there an exception class that would be state of the art for this purpose?

Comment: @krzaq I prefer to have full control within main to escape the *static initialisation nightmare*.

Comment: `std::runtime_error` or derrive from it if you need custom things. Though if you **always** have a Sys and it is not optional you can use a static variable and you don't have to use an exception

Comment: I don't see how it can be both optional and "created first and destroyed last".

Comment: Throwing something derived from `std::runtime_error` sounds great to me, would you build an answer from this?

Comment: ok. I can do this.

Comment: @molbdnilo [rephrased](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40305659/2). Thanks for pointing me on that confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While asserts can be removed in a release mode you may be better of by throwing an exception instead.

Your program may crash by just using the null pointer without exception but this is undefined behavior and can have all possible side effects.

An exception also has the advantages that the objects you created get cleaned up (stack unwind) and you also have the chance to catch the exception and deal with it if you have a part of your code where you are able to properly deal with this.

You can throw whatever you like, but it is recommended to throw anything derived from `std::exception`. `std::runtime_error` seems good here. Or derive something yourself.

One thing to note though:

Because you are working on a global object (singletons are also global) you should avoid using the singleton in a destructor. When an exception gets thrown and you are "stack-unwinding" and one of those objects destructors would throw a second exception the program will immediately call `std::terminate`. If you terminate anyway this might not be a problem, but if you want to catch the exception somewhere or you rely on stack-unwinding this may lead to issues.

Comment: *`avoid using the singleton in a destructor`* -- good point, indeed I plan to provide optional access (i.e. a pointer that can be checked) as well.

Comment: Accepted so far because focused on the core of my question.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that an optional system object introduces lots of not-null checking code.

Consider replacing it with a null object:

```
class MySys {
    virtual void some_op() = 0;
    // other operations here
};

class NullSystem: public MySys {
    void some_op() {} // no-op implementations for all APIs
};

class YourSystem: public MySys {
    void some_op() { /* your non-optional implementation here */ }
};
```

> I know that dereferencing a null pointer results in undefined behaviour. Is using the good old C-assert the best I can do?

First, don't use a global for the instance and don't use a singleton access point (your `MySys::Instance()`). The singleton pattern is an anti-pattern (it shows mostly what not to do).

Consider instantiating an object in main and passing that around by reference (that is, use dependency injection instead of singletons):

```
class SomeClientClass
{
    SomeClientClass(MySys const & system);
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    auto system = std::make_unique<YourSystem>();

    auto someClientCode = SomeClientClass(*system);
    // ... 

    // example where you want a SomeClientClass instance without system:
    auto client2 = SomeClientClass{ NullSystem{} };
}
```

Comment: The passing around is my actual problem, so I decided to accept the de-facto availability of a "global" object.

Comment: For availability, simply inject it into the code that uses it, as a parameter: for objects, pass a reference in the constructor of the object; for functions, simply add it as a parameter. You will be at more of an advantage by passing around an extra argument, than you will be by declaring a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You might simply do something like:

```
MySys& MySys::Instance()
{
    static MySysImplementation instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is problematic for getting the non-trivial cleanup under control.

Comment: I [clarified the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40305659/3) to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

> Is using the good old C-assert the best I can do?

It's one option. Whether it's best depends on what you need the program to do when a null pointer is used.

There are two aspects of assert:

1. It is disabled conditionally, depending on the `NDEBUG` macro - which is typically enabled in a release build. If you would like to detect the null pointer unconditionally, an `if` statement is a better alternative.
2. It calls `std::abort` which terminates the process. If the situation could be resolved in a more graceful manner, then assertion isn't the best option for you. Instead, you could throw an exception, and catch it higher in the call stack where it can be handled.

If you cannot handle the exception meaningfully anyway, and if you prefer to avoid the runtime cost of the check in the release build, then assertion is indeed best that you can do.

---

However if possible, you might alternatively guarantee that the object does necessarily exist by using a static instance. Consider following:

```
MySys& MySys::Instance()
{
    static MySysImplementation sys;
    return sys;
}
```

This `sys` is guaranteed to exist before and after any object, that calls `MySys::Instance` within its constructor - or whose construction is otherwise guaranteed to be after the `MySysImplementation` has been constructed.

Comment: First, assert might really be a bad idea. Second, since the cleanup is non-trivial, the static-variable approach isn't an option in my case.

Comment: @Wolf OK, I added "if possible" qualification to the suggestion. What do you mean by non-trivial cleanup?